# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool'

Tags: c#

```
if ((!s.IsValidCashFlow) && (s.Cash.InvalidCashFlowReason == InvalidCashFlowReason.IAmAPoorMF))
```

I guess you can't do this in C#?  isValidCashFlow is a bool property

updated:

the error is actually in my .ascx, wrong place:

```
<div id="Div1" " runat="server" visible="<%#(!Container.DataItem.IsValidCashFlow && (Product)Container.DataItem.Product)InvalidCashFlowReason == InvalidCashFlowReason.IAmAPoorMF %>">
```

Resolved: I added the extra () as the compiler was getting confused:

```
<div id="Div1" " runat="server" visible="<%#(!Container.DataItem.IsValidCashFlow && ((Product)Container.DataItem.Product)InvalidCashFlowReason == InvalidCashFlowReason.IAmAPoorMF) %>">
```

Comment: LOL for the "InvalidCashFlowReason.IAmAPoorMF".  You can definitely use the logical AND operator on two bools though, not sure what the issue is.

Comment: The code is not clear - state your intentions... I am guessing here that the right hand side of the statement in the if expression is comparing an enum? Please clarify?

Comment: the error is actually in my .ascx, wrong place: <div id="Div1" " runat="server" visible="<%#(!Container.DataItem.IsValidCashFlow && (Product)Container.DataItem.Product)InvalidCashFlowReason == InvalidCashFlowReason.IAmAPoorMF %>">

Comment: yes, right side is an enum.  both have to be true therefore is why I have the &&.  Left side is checking a boolean property.  Right side is checking to see if a value == an enum value.

Comment: good God, how did I get a -2?  lol

Comment: anyway resolved.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely do this, but there must be something else going on. Can you present a more complete code sample, and print the compiler error?

Comment: it was actually something in my .aspx....my fault.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply `&&` between bools. Everything in a conditional evaluates to bools, so if `&&` ever works, it's being applied to multiple bool values.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce:

```
var t = new { InvalidCashFlowReason = InvalidCashFlowReason.IAmAPoorMF};
var s = new {IsValidCashFlow = true, Cash = t};
if ((!s.IsValidCashFlow) &&
    (s.Cash.InvalidCashFlowReason == InvalidCashFlowReason.IAmAPoorMF))
{}
```

What *exact* compiler version are you using? Is something else amiss?